# CartoDB-Picture not showed inside Infowindow

Tags: carto, infowindow

I am trying to customize my infowindow in cartodb but the picture is not showed.
I have the same picture uplooad into google drive and dropbox in two differents formats *.jpeg and *.png but it does not work....

[image]

[image]

Any idea why? Maybe I must upload in another public place....

Comment: what is the url to one of the images? If it opens in your browser, then it is a problem with the configuration

Answer (score 1):

The image URLs must be direct links to the images. URLs such as Flickr links, which are loading the image "inside their site", but without being it an explicit link for the image itself, won't work. This happens with a lot of different image hosting sites. Dropbox or Google Drive also load an image viewer instead of returning the image itself.

In Imgur for example, you have the "direct link" and the "share link". The share link loads the image inside the imgur site, so it won't work in the infowindows, but the direct link will, as it just retrieves the image resource.

Comment: Hi, Thanks in advance for your help but It still does´t work. The image is on dropbox: https://www.dropbox.com/s/hw15f47nubvwybq/P1.png?dl=0, I can load it directly from internet but don´t from cartodb info window. I don´t understand properly toy answer, do you have any code example?. Thanks, Juanjo

Comment: Notice that your URL is opening the image inside the Dropbox site. This one would be a direct URL: https://photos-1.dropbox.com/t/2/AADI3-e7D0Xznq26NNG9BMTizNQ-njadP1B2EMmPLMX8tg/12/9215755/png/32x32/3/1450980000/0/2/P1.png/EN3U7gYY7gwgBygH/5BXbuKX4bDlEcnkZuRVFhbTpCkq8j2YgnJ1iDJDgqVA?size_mode=3&size=1024x768

Comment: Thanks a lot!! but how Can I transform my URL into the new one as your example?

Comment: You'd want to use your Dropbox Public folder. Though, 2017-2018 I think they are changing their policy for displaying some things like webpages. Another option is GitHub, using the raw file url.